# create a list box in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a simple way to present values in a list box in Ruby on Rails ? 
(something like adding the html select tag multiple attribute in ruby)

Comment: What environment? Rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean this?

```
select_tag "list[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@collection, "id", "name"), :multiple=>true
```