# How to sort list after changing category in select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I used following answer to create list of categories in my view

[create a list box in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366482/create-a-list-box-in-ruby-on-rails)

and after choosing one of categories, I'd like to list below has elements from selected category. Every item of that list has field category_id. How can I realize it? Is any possibility to call from select_tag function in controller, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`order`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) to get your ordered list. If you want categories list in ascending order (according to their name), the following would do your work:

```
@categories = Category.all.order(:name)
```

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to choose this name from listbox and then create list. I don't know how to capture selected name from select_tag. I'm sorry, I formed my question wrong